# SQL field with multiple id's of other table

Tags: sql, row, field

Could someone give me an idea how to create this database structure.
Here is an example:

```
Table "countries":
id, countryname
1, "US"
2, "DE"
3, "FR"
4, "IT"
```

Now I have another table "products" and in there I would like to store all countries where this product is available:

```
Table "products":
id,productname,countries
1,"product1",(1,2,4) // available in countries US, DE, IT.
2,"product2",(2,3,4) // available in countries DE, FR, IT.
```

My question:
How do I design the table structure in "products" to be able to store multiple countries?

My best idea is to put a comma-separated string in there (i.e. "1,2,4"), then split that string to look up each entry. But I doubt that this the best way to do this?

EDIT: Thank you all for your help, amazing! It was difficult to choose the right answer, 
I finally chose Gregs because he pointed me to a JOIN explanation and gave an example how to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need an intersection table for that [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship.

```
Table Country
CountryID, CountryName

Table CountryProduct
CountryID, ProductID

Table Product
ProductID, ProductName
```

You then [Inner Join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) all 3 tables to get your list of Countries & Products.

```
Select * From Country 
Inner Join CountryProduct On Country.CountryID = CountryProduct.CountryID 
Inner Join Product On CountryProduct.ProductID = Product.ProductID
```

Answer (score 3):

Without denormalizing, you'll need to add an extra table

```
Table Product countries
ProductID CountryID
1         1
1         2
1         4...
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is normalisation. You have a many-to-many structure, so you should create another table to link the two. You should never (ok, pretty much never) use delimited strings to store a list of values in a relational database.

Here's an example of the setup:

```
product_countries table

productid | countryid
----------+-----------
1         | 1
1         | 2
1         | 4
2         | 2
2         | 3
2         | 4
```

You can use a foreign key to each other table, then make them both into a composite primary key.

You can then get a list of supported products for a country ID like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products, product_countries
WHERE products.id = product_countries.productid
AND product_countries.countryid = $cid
```

Comment: why not using a join? this always looks a bit odd to me

Comment: The logic when using a `JOIN` would be more confusing to an SQL newbie, which the OP clearly is. Sure, a `JOIN` would work too, but without it the logic is clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you and all others for helping!! Yes, SQL-newbie here. One subquestion: That SQL-statement seems slow to me - suppose I have 100000+ products, wouldn't that take a long time to iterate through product_countries?

Comment: Shouldn't do. Since both columns are both primary and foreign keys, they'll be indexed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a third table countries_products with fields country_id and product_id.

Answer (score 1):

the best approach for relational databases is the following :

One table for coutries, let's say
country_id, country_desc  (country_id is primary)

one table for products, let's say
product_id, product_desc and as many columns as you want (product_id is primary)

if you had only one country for sure, it'd be enough to have a foreign key pointing to country_id in each product row. Having a foreign key asserts that there is an actual country behing a country_id referring to country table.

In your case you have several countries for a product, so add a separate association table
product_id, country_id

both keys primary and both foreign as well.