# SQL: Basics on JOINs and other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I think I need a hint in which direction to go.
Following up on my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062465/sql-field-with-multiple-ids-of-other-table), I'm trying to implement a sql query on 3 tables with **MySQL**.

Table 1: "base" info on a product

```
id, productnumber
1,45
```

Table 2: "country_specifics" for each product id

```
id, countrycode,name
1,"DE","Produkt 1"
1,"US","Product 1"
```

Ok, a

```
SELECT B.id,C.name,C.countrycode 
FROM base AS B 
INNER JOIN country_specifics AS C ON B.id=C.id
WHERE B.id=1 AND C.countrycode='US';
```

gives me what I want:

```
1,"Product 1","US"
```

**BUT:**

I have a third table:

Table 3: "features" for each product id

```
id,feature
1,"feature 1"
1,"feature 2"
```

and the end result of my query should somehow additionaly contain the features a product has. 
I tried that with an additional

```
INNER JOIN features AS F ON b.id=f.id
```

but that will return two rows (and I understand why):

```
1,"Product 1","US","feature 1"
1,"Product 1","US","feature 2"
```

but I think this is not what I want.
What I want is a sort of array for the feature field:

1,"Product 1","US","feature 1,feature 2"

as a result. I know (or am fairly certain) there are no arrays in SQL, but what is the closest to that? Can I do that in 1 query? Obviously, I could simply start a second query, but is that the best option? 
For which keyword should I google?

Thanks for reading, marimba

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your help, really!

I just would like to clarify my question: I don't necessarily need an array or something close to it. I would like to understand what the best (most efficient, least error-prone) approach would be to get "all data for this product".

If you tell me accepting 2 rows as a result and work with that is the best way, I'll do that. 
I just think when they designed SQL, they thought of this problem and had a solution ready, and I am trying to find that solution.

**EDIT 2:**

Again, I'm apologizing for misleading people into thinking I need a comma-separated string. I tried to illustrate what kind of data I was expecting.

I appreciate the pointer to `group_concat`, but I have the feeling a `stored procedure` with 2 queries, as outlined by jmacinnes and Sachin, is the cleaner way.

Thank you, stackoverflow community.

Comment: This is for Sybase ASE, SQL Server, Oracle, MYSQL?

Comment: mysql - from the second sentence in the first paragraph.

Comment: @marimba - **Are** you using MySQL? (There are different approaches in different flavours of SQL to resolving this issue.)

Comment: Yes, MySQL. I bolded this now. I thought it doesn't matter so much, but I begin to understand that there is no standard solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it using the single query that you have already written. Then,  simply format that data to be displayed the way you want in your application layer. You can loop through the results and group all of the features for each product together.

Though it is possible to return the result set you are after, it would be a bad practice to do so. It would make parsing the data a lot harder if the features table were to change in the future.

If the duplicated data you would get by joining to the Features table is significant, then you could return two result sets in a single stored procedure:

```
SELECT B.id,C.name,C.countrycode 
FROM base AS B 
INNER JOIN country_specifics AS C ON B.id=C.id
WHERE B.id=1 AND C.countrycode='US';

SELECT id featureId FROM features where ProductId = 1
```

Comment: I am wondering about this: Supposed there are 25 features for product 1. That would result in 25 rows, of which 24 are only needed for the feature id. Isn't that inefficient in terms of bandwidth, memory, looping?

Comment: From a CPU perspective, I suspect returning the data directly will be faster than concatenating it on the database. Databases are not very good at string parsing. Also, it pushes load to your database that can be easily be done at the application layer. Generally speaking, its a lot easier to scale your webservers than your databases. In terms of bandwidth, if you were returning a lot of data that was being duplicated between product rows, you could change your single stored procedure to return multiple result sets.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid it's going to be a lot of data for various products and features. Could you elaborate a bit more on "change your single stored procedure to return multiple result sets"? I don't understand that...

Comment: Ok, got it, thank you! So using 2 queries, albeit combined, is the SQL  way. I think this is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a function or a stored procedure that takes in an id and then for the features table returns a string with all the features with that id.  Then you can use that in your original query.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using MySQL, you can use group_concat:

```
SELECT B.id,C.name,C.countrycode, group_concat(F.feature) as feature_list 
FROM base AS B 
INNER JOIN country_specifics AS C ON B.id=C.id
WHERE B.id=1 AND C.countrycode='US'
INNER JOIN features AS F ON B.id=F.id
GROUP BY B.id
```

Comment: Which is why I said, "Because you are using MySQL" - see the second sentence in the first paragraph of the question.

Comment: I just found a nice example for group_concat and the author had exactly the problem I have, so it seems this is the way to go...although I wonder. But thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The below solution is Oracle based, you can try to implement the same in MySQL

you can create a database function as below

```
create or replace function prod_feature(p_product_id in number) return varchar2
    v_feature varchar2(2000) := '';
    i number := 0 ;
begin
    for c1rec in (select feature from table3 where product_id = p_product_id) loop
       if i = 0 then
           v_feature:= v_feature|| c1rec.feature;
       else
           v_feature:= v_feature|| ', ' || c1rec.feature;
       end if;
       i  := i +1;
    end loop;
    return v_feature;
end;
```

then use this function in the first sql

```
SELECT B.id,C.name,C.countrycode, prod_feature(id) 
FROM base AS B 
INNER JOIN country_specifics AS C ON B.id=C.id
WHERE B.id=1 AND C.countrycode='US';
```

Comment: You can use the `{}` button when typing code to format it as code - I have amended your answer to format the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this. Try this, see if it works the way you want.

```
SELECT id, name, code, GROUP_CONCAT(fea) features FROM 
(  
  SELECT id, name, code, f.feature fea FROM 
  (
    SELECT b.id id, cs.name name, cs.countrycode code FROM 
    base b
    JOIN country_specifics cs
    ON cs.id = b.id
    AND cs.countrycode = "US"
   ) a
 JOIN features f
 ON f.id = a.id  
) b
GROUP BY id
```