# How to save array of int in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am working on swift app with php and mysql. I have cartel and orderTbl. The cartId is a foreign key in order table. A user can add more than one item in cart. So now I have a user with two cart items and I am trying to checkout but the cartId foreign key can only save one Id and I also have two Ids it can be more but I want to use two for this example. The cartId is an array like so [93, 95]. Now my problem is how to save them. 
I have read the below solution

[SQL field with multiple id's of other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062465/sql-field-with-multiple-ids-of-other-table)

now I have created
cartOrderTbl which has both the cartId and orderID as foreign keys but my challenge now is how to save them.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Create a relational one-to-many structure and insert into that. If you're not sure what that is, time to read up on the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) as applied to
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: "my challenge now is how to save them" - How about using an `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @tadman .. I have created the many to many relationship now my issues is how to save the [93, 95] in the relationship table.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel. the data is an array and I know I can't just use insert statement in the array, Is there a function I can call to split the array into separate ints.. thanks

Comment: Remember that we're not psychic here, you'll need to describe what you've done in specific technical terms as well as what you're intending to do and the expected results. If you have a schema, that's great, but it would be better if you could edit your question and include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for it. If you have N values you need to insert into a one-to-many table usually you `prepare` a statement of the form `INSERT INTO join_table (a_id, b_value) VALUES (?,?)` and then execute N times for pairs like `[1, 93]` and `[1, 95]` where `1` is your parent record's ID value.